# Set Default selection for GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anyone guide me how set particular element of grid view as selected ?

**.setSelection(positionOfItem)** is not working .

```
gridViewSize  =  (GridView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.grid_sizes);
        gridViewSize.setAdapter(new PopupSizeAdapter(context,typeArr,1));
        gridViewSize.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: setSelection cannot be called at this point, I think. you need to wait for your list to be displayed

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me

```
mGridView.setSelection(pos);
mGridView.requestFocusFromTouch();
mGridView.setSelection(pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue today, following is my solution:

```
GridView.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(getLayoutListener(mGridView))
private static ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener getLayoutListener(final GridView mGridView) {
    ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            View view = mGridView.getChildAt(0);
            if(view != null) {
                if(!view.isSelected()) {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                } else {
                    // remove the listener after the first time.
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                        mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    return listener;
}
```

and also, if you are using android API >= 11, you can also add a View.OnLayoutChangeListener to GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid.performItemClick(view, position, id);
```

Then my state drawable works correctly on GridView.